# Bootstrap 5 hidden elements and jquery fadeToggle not playing well

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap 5, and I would like to fade in/out a particular div element. jQuery has a nifty function called `fadeToggle()` for doing this exact thing, so I thought I might use it.

The expected behavior is:

- `div` element is hidden initially with `d-none` class
- Click on the button link to toggle fade in/out on the div

However, Bootstrap's `d-none` doesn't seem to play well with jQuery's `fadeToggle()`, what ends up happening is the `div` element pops in without fading in **on the first click**. Subsequent clicks on the button link will fade correctly because the `d-none` class is never added back, so jQuery takes over the hiding/showing of the element. Fading out works fine though.

Here is an example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
     <a href="#">Click me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="one d-none">
       1 of 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="two">
       2 of 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="three">
       3 of 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

jquery script:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $(".one").fadeToggle(1200, function() {
            $(".one").toggleClass("d-none") 
    });
});
```

---

Here is a live example, just refresh the page after the first click to see what I mean about popping in instead of fading incorrectly:

https://codepen.io/iosub/pen/oNdLzgV

---

**How can I get jQuery to play nice with Bootstrap's `d-none` class so that I can fade in/out seamlessly?**

*As a bonus question*, is there a convention for using jquery + bootstrap together? I feel using display properties like `d-none` messes with what jquery expects when an element is 'hidden' and such, leading to weird behavior like the above. Should jquery just take over in controlling these display properties, or should bootstrap classes be added back in after jquery finishes? (ie, add back `d-none` after `fadeToggle()` fades out, and remove it when `fadeToggle()` fades in. Currently, it just removes the entire `d-none` class and hands control over to jquery instead)

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code. Hope It will work.

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $(".one").fadeToggle(1200, function() {
            
    });
  $(".one").removeClass("d-none") 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery acts well with bootstrap so go on with coding. But there are some traps you caught in this one.

bootstrap d-none class applies to element display: none style to an element. But jQuery toggle plays with opacity across 0 (totally transparent and 1 opaque)

so when you use it with the initial state displayed none it shows with no animation because there is no effects with opacity due visibility is initially none so when d-none is removed by callback jQuery apply its rules about opacity due to visibility not affecting its style.

Remember an element displayed none tells the browser I'm here but not show me. An element with opacity 0 tells the browser I'm here but with transparent color.

To reach the desired effect remove d-none and outside of click trigger init element with .hide() Which applies opacity: 0 to element style

Answer (score 0):

```js
setInterval(function(){
   $("#anyId").fadeTo(200,0.2).fadeTo(200,1);
},401)
```

```html
<html><head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="anyId">Blinking text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).